# Reclassification Issues - Conditional Statements to Change Raster Values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, arcgis-10.4, reclassify, conditional

I am looking for help with the statement to put into Raster Calculator that would turn some incorrect raster values (discrete values from 1385-1399) into a "1" without changing the majority of raster cells with correctly assigned values (1-14).

[image: The output of the Reclassify tool.]

Background: When I run the Reclassify tool (Spatial Analyst) on my DEM in ArcGIS, which has an elevation range of 1385-2629 masl, it never works perfectly. The first class is supposed to be <1400, but instead I get classes for 1385, 1386, 1387, 1388, 1389, 1 (1390-1399), 2 (1400-1499) etc. I work with large, high rez datasets (100 km2 area, 1m cell size) and reclassification issues always seem to arise where at least one class is created containing only the minimum or maximum value(s) regardless. I read that this is a known issue with earlier versions of Arc but I am using 10.4.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE Kelsey. Could you include the raster calculator statement that has not been working for you. Also, it is best to stick to a single focused question rather than lumping two questions together--you can always ask a second or third question.

Comment: The simplest way is bringing raster to map, create classified symbology and run reclassify tool. By default it will accept classes from symbology

Comment: Thanks Aaron - I edited the post because what seemed like a second question was really just background information on what I was trying to fix with Raster Calculator. I haven't crafted a statement yet - hence my post here :)!